# remove hidden field based on hidden field value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i would like to remove a hidden field from the form using jquery based on hidden field value.

please look the below html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myvalue[]" value="value1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="myvalue[]" value="value2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="myvalue[]" value="value3"/>
```

i have jquery function which returns me the above value example:

```
$('#getValue').click(function(){

  .... processing code here.....

  return valueOfHiddenField;
});
```

now i would like to remove the hidden field from the form based on the value return by the `getValue`

so if the method returns me `value1` then any input hidden field in the form with value as `value1` should be removed. in this case the first input field of my html above.

any help or suggestion would be a great help ... thanks in advance

Comment: you can iterate over them using `$('input:hidden').each(function () { if (this.value == 'value1') {$(this).remove()} }`

Comment: @Pilot thank you sir works like charm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('input[type="hidden"][value="+YOUR_VALUEVAR+"]').remove();
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9tsgy/

Comment: thank you sir..as i know that i only want to remove hidden input.. how can i write so that it only checks hidden input field in the form.. so it will work fast.

Comment: Change it to: `$("input[type="hidden"][value='+YOUR_VALUEVAR+']").remove();`

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over `input:hidden` elements to check values and `remove()` based on value,

```
$("input:hidden").each(function () {
    if (this.value == "value1") { // your condition here
        $(this).remove()
    }
}
```

Comment: @Muhammad glad to help..you can always mark ans as correct if it satisfies your requirement so that other will find it easy

Comment: thank you very much Pilot sir for your important time given to me.. but i am more satisfied with the Rick Lancee sir answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#getValue').click(function () {
    $(document).find("input[type=hidden]").each(function () {
        if ($(this).value == 'Your Value') {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
    return valueOfHiddenField;
});
```

Comment: where is the explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:

```
let hiddenValue = $(this).val();
$('input[type="hidden"][value="'+hiddenValue+'"]').remove();
```

Get the value of a hidden field and then use it dynamically and remove specific  `<input type="hidden">`